# Are methods instance or class attributes in Python?

Tags: python, class, methods, attributes, instance

Just wondering... I know methods are basically callable attributes of your object. But, if so, are they class or instance attributes ?

I've noticed that if you do:

```
class A:
    def test(self):
        print("test")

A.test(0)
```

You get:

```
test
```

I've noted that you have to pass the self parameter explicitly, which you wouldn't usually do, but other than that, the method (which doesn't even use self and, like Pycharm likes to point out, could be made static) well... works. So that seems to point out to the fact that methods would be class attributes.

Any precisions to add on that ?

Comment: You can always call an unbound method from the class and pass an instance explicitly as the first argument (which would not be needed if you were calling the same method as a method bound to an instance). In your example, what you are passing is not an instance, but it happens to work because the method does not actually use `self`.

Comment: @alani Right! I forgot about that possibility. Thanks for the reminder.